# How to plot mnemonic maps (shape with string inside) in Python using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In digital electronics, during a simulation, it is common to represent instructions of a CPU, the state of an FSM, etc using text. These strings are placed inside a hexagon-like shape.

So, I would like to be able to pass a string, or a list of strings, and plot the information as in the picture below, where state1, state2, etc are the different strings. I am doing the script in Python and using Matplolib.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom box style for that!
(see https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/userdemo/custom_boxstyle01.html)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import BoxStyle
from matplotlib.path import Path

def custom_box_style(x0, y0, width, height, mutation_size):
    """
    Given the location and size of the box, return the path of the box around
    it.

    Rotation is automatically taken care of.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x0, y0, width, height : float
        Box location and size.
    mutation_size : float
        Mutation reference scale, typically the text font size.
    """
    # padding
    mypad = 0.4
    pad = mutation_size * mypad
    # width and height with padding added.
    width = width + 2 * pad
    height = height + 2 * pad
    # boundary of the padded box
    x0, y0 = x0 - pad, y0 - pad
    x1, y1 = x0 + width, y0 + height
    
    # return the new path
    return Path([(x0, y0),
                 (x1, y0), (x1 + pad, (y0 + y1)/2), (x1, y1), (x0, y1),
                 (x0 - pad, (y0 + y1)/2), (x0, y0),
                 (x0, y0)],
                closed=True)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 1))
for i in range(5):
    ax.text(0.1 + i/5, 0.5, "Test", size=15, va="center", ha="center", 
            bbox=dict(boxstyle=custom_box_style),
            transform=ax.transAxes)
```

[image]